# does user search form show results with wrong rep points?

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, reputation, user-interface

I was searching for a user by name and the form found it but it showed 0 points (I know he has more than that). So I searched for MY profile, and this form apparently shows wrong rep points aside the user search results... maybe?

[image: discrepancy in rep from the users page and my rep]

ok, not fundamental, but maybe it should be fixed, later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, no problem here.

Look over on the right of the users page, you will see five buttons "week, month, quarter, year, all."

In that screen shot you were viewing the "Month" page. Which sorts the users biased on how much rep they have gotten in the current month. The rep count displayed is also correlated to what page you are looking at (In this case a month).

Just hover over anyone's rep and you will see it says "reputation this month: X total reputation: X."

[image: example image of monthly rep]

Just a note: *It is a calendar month and not the previous 30 days, like in some other places.*

If you want to have that rep number display total rep, just click on the [all](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) button.

Comment: oh gosh... of course... I'll never get used to all the options... :(